# libpng linking errors in electric?

Tags: ubuntu-natty, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to run some stuff from ROS electric on my laptop running Ubuntu 11.04 amd64. Things like Rviz, or anything that uses images really, seems to give warnings like the following:

```
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.44 but running with 1.5.4
```

which is bizarre because I only have 1.2.44 installed, and I even checked with ldd and it should be finding the right version of libpng. I don't even know how I could have a newer version of libpng, and it can't have been statically linked to 1.5.4 because then it wouldn't have been compiled against 1.2.44, right? I would just ignore the error but occasionally things randomly crash giving PNG related errors, which seems like a bad thing to have happen. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11320/libpng-linking-errors-in-electric?/) by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2011-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2011-09-27**:
I really don't have any idea why this error comes up. To clarify, it happens as soon as rviz launches when the splash screen attempts to be displayed, and in fact I don't get any images in ROS programs.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-27**:
When I run rviz on Ubuntu 11.04 with Electric, I do not see that error. Do I need to display an image to see that error message? I have libpng 1.2.44 installed, just as you do, and the rviz binary references it.

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2012-05-17**:
How did you solve this problem? I have similar problem (same warning and no icons) on Ubuntu 11.10. x64.

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2012-11-07**:
I honestly have no idea :( I want to jump in my TARDIS and slap past me for not providing a resolution. Most likely the solution ended up being nuking the setup and starting over from scratch or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"ldd" might help you find out what's happening.

```
 ldd /path/to/rviz
```

This will list the shared libraries that it uses.

---

Originally posted by [glennrp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1148/glennrp/) with karma: 26 on 2011-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1